# How to make "draft margin notes" for floats?

Tags: floats, memoir, marginpar

Page 394 of the [memoir manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) provides a snippet by Bastian Veelo for making margin comments out over the part of the stock paper that would be cut away. This very handy for making comments only appearing in the draft.

However if I want to comment a float like for example a figure it complains about not being in outer par mode. How can I adopt the code:

```
\documentclass[draft]{memoir}

\makeatletter
\ifdraftdoc
\newlength{\draftnotewidth} 
\newlength{\draftnotesignwidth} 
\newcommand{\draftnote}[1]{\@bsphack%
{%% do not interfere with settings for other marginal notes 
\strictpagecheck% 
\checkoddpage%
\setlength{\draftnotewidth}{\foremargin}% 
\addtolength{\draftnotewidth}{\trimedge}% 
\addtolength{\draftnotewidth}{-3\marginparsep}% 
\ifoddpage
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{\draftnotewidth}%
\marginpar{\flushleft\textbf{\textit{\HUGE !\ }}\small #1}% 
\else
\settowidth{\draftnotesignwidth}{\textbf{\textit{\HUGE\ !}}}% 
\addtolength{\draftnotewidth}{-\draftnotesignwidth}% 
\marginpar{\raggedleft\makebox[0pt][r]{%% hack around
}% \fi
\parbox[t]{\draftnotewidth}{%%%%%%%%% funny behaviour 
\raggedleft\small\hspace{0pt}#1%
}}\textbf{\textit{\HUGE\ !}}%
}\@esphack} \else
\newcommand{\draftnote}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack} \fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\draftnote{Lorem ipsum}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

to work also with floats?

Comment: `\marginpar`s are floats, and TeX doesn't allow floats inside floats. (Thanks to egreg for the tip.) Use the `marginnote` package and its command of the same name to define a new `\draftnote` command from scratch.

Comment: why? `memoir` has several other margin writing macros, like `\sidepar` and friends. Several of these are not floats and thus can be used within floats.

Comment: @daleif: I stand corrected. I should have said: `\draftnote` won't work, but chances are high the `memoir` authors have come up with another command tailor-made for your problem.

Comment: @lockstep: Okey, that sounds promising. Only remains finding such a tailor-made command then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the `\marginnote` macro from the `marginnote` package. It produces something similar to `\marginpar`, but it is not a float. I made a small example. In principle you should be able to replace the two `\marginpar`s with `\marginnote`s, but the upper code does not work for me, even if the `\draftnote` command is outside of the figure environment, so I could not try that.

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
\marginnote{This is a comment}
\caption{I am a caption}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I fail to see in what way this is relevant for my problem. I wanted to put a margin comment at the same height as a float found inside the textblock area. Such a comment would not be a graphic and it would not have a figure caption. Am I missing something?

Comment: I hope this is what you were asking for now.